# Chrome - css img float listmark is not displayed on the right place

Tags: css

In the following coding, the listmark is placed on top of the image only if it is displayed in Chrome.
(Float is effective for text, it will be displayed on the right side of the image without problems)
Also, when refresh with F5, the listmark will be displayed on the right side of the image without problems.
To prevent the listmark from being placed on top of the image from the beginning, could someone please tell me what to do?

```css
img {
  float: left;
}

ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="images/sample.jpg" alt="sample" width="50%" />
  <ul>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>bbb</li>
    <li>ccc</li>
    <li>ddd</li>
    <li>eee</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Updates:
When the list gets long, I want the lists wrap images like below.
https://embed.plnkr.co/uo1u4YOQHAWpFEO117QG/

Comment: you could float your ul right or give it a width less than 50% - 20px

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/uo1u4YOQHAWpFEO117QG/

Please take a look at this. When the list is long, I want to place the list below the images.

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul{
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="images/sample.jpg" alt="sample" width="50%" />
  <ul>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>bbb</li>
    <li>ccc</li>
    <li>ddd</li>
    <li>eee</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
img {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: thank you for your help, however, I would like to place img on left, and list on right side.

Comment: @Hashimo Like that?

Comment: Thank you again!
One more thing, when the lists are long and want to wrap around the image, is there different way?
When I try on my local environment was no problem (listmark is right side of the image), however when I released on server, the listmark is on the image just happens on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to float your `<ul>` like so:

```
ul{
    float: left;
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
}
```

That should float everything and the ul will always be on the right side of the image.